# Read/Write NVM on Cellphone?

Tags: read-write, cdma, nvm

I'm trying to read/write NVM on a Qualcomm based cellphone (cdma) using Win32.

LG provides drivers so that the phone is available over serial port when hot plugged. I can open the port as expected.

But I'm not sure how one goes about reading and writing NV items. My Google-fu is off today, so I have not gotten any useful hits.

I downloaded the sources for BitPim, but I'm not a Python guy. I thought I might be able to gain some information from filesystem.py, but its the code to manage the GUI views (???).

I also tried using SysInternal's PortMon while using CDMA Workshop, but PortMon does not capture the port (apparently, it only allows captures on ports which are present, and not device interfaces which come and go).

Does anyone have any information or experience?

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to connect to the serial port, or DM port and construct proper QCDM packets to send to the device.

You can look at a linux application called ModemManager, it includes a library in it called `libqcdm` - If you are familiar with C, you can take a look at how it constructs its QCDM packets and you can re-create them in any language that supports writing to serial ports.

I started on a similar software to CDMA Workshop for some in-house use since I work in the retail cell phone industry and looking at the sources of this application also helped me a lot:

http://code.google.com/p/cdmaworkshoptool/

In addition to that application, I found some Chinese website with some CDMA C++ sources which helped me a lot as well. (while not a really friendly website to get the download from, you can click on the individual source files to read the code through your browser)

http://www.pudn.com/downloads125/sourcecode/windows/comm/detail529045.html

Comment: check out usblyzer or another port sniffer, maybe try sniffing qxdm if cdmaWS has built in anti-reversing code (alternatively in cdmaDevTerm / cdmaWorkshopTool which I develop and is posted above there is a log tab with the equivalent of what you get in most port sniffers)